# Trusting a certificate by trusting only part of the certificates

Tags: cryptography, certificate, public-key-encryption, pki

Assume I have Alice's certificate, and its certificate chain is built out of N certificates. Is it enough to verify (and trust) the root of the chain (for instance, VeriSign), or do I have to trust (and verify) each and every certificate?

Out of my understanding, I need to trust and time validate the root of the chain certificate and **only** time validate all the other certificates in the chain. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must perform validation of each certificate in the chain, and more - you need to use CRLs and OCSP servers (when the corresponding information is available in the certificates), and as CRLs and OCSP responses are signed, you need to build certificate chains there and validate all of them as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :-)
But why isn't it enough to time validate and check the CRL for all the certificate, and fully verify just the root ???

Comment: @TCS Actually the root is trusted (you can't validate it because you don't have an anchor besides an exclicit trust -- the root is self-signed). Other certificates can be revoked, so you need to check their validity/revocation status. Of course you need to check signature integrity for each certificate as well. Now, certificates are issued for particular purpose (use) and KeyUsage/ExtKeyUsage fields must be checked to ensure that the code-signing certificate is not used for SSL or vice versa (for example).